# Override video tag requests mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am currently building a desktop app with electron, in which I include html5 `<video/>` tags.

For my first implementation, I was setting the `src` with a file URI (ex: `'file:///Users/bobby/Desktop/video.mp4'`).

Problem was that the performances were awful (really long load time, the video took at least 2 seconds to change between each click on the time bar). In my current implementation, to fix those issues, I am launching in parallel with my app, a static-files server on localhost to serve the video files. I think this solution is really dirty and overkill.

Is there a clean way to feed the video tags with data read from a node `fs` stream? I was thinking about overriding the partial requests mechanism with a callback which would return my data, but from my current reading and understanding of the API, this is not possible.

Comment: What kind of encoding do you have on the video? How big are they?

Comment: mp4, quiet big, like 1GB and more

Answer (score 0):

The performance issues you're having are most likely related to either the file size, encoding depth or resolution. Big videos load slower and play slower. Seeking is also usually slower because the player has to spend time buffering from the file system before it can start or resume playing.

Try re-encoding at lower bit rates and resolutions to see if performance improves. It's usually better to upscale than downscale. Additionally, experiment with how far apart you space your keyframes. More frequent keyframes will usually increase file size but can make seeking faster.